# getting data from text file but ajax.status = 0

Tags: jquery, ajax

hi i'm using this very simple code on my localhost to get data from a text file

```
    $("#getdata").click(function(){
    var ajax = false;
    ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
    ajax.open("get","data.txt");
    ajax.onreadystatechange = function(){
        alert(ajax.status);
        if(ajax.readyState == 4 && ajax.status == 200){
            $(".content").html(ajax.responseText);
        }
    }
    ajax.send(null);
});
```

but i get 0 as ajax.status. I've tried this also

```
$("#getdata").click(function(){
$.ajax({url:"data.txt",success:function(result){
alert("done");
}});
});
```

but it doesn't alert. Any help ?

Comment: as you are use jquery, why don't just use `JQuery.Ajax()` ?

Comment: but i want to know the problem with this code not just looking for any solution

Comment: Where is your data.txt actually? Perhaps the code can't find it.

Comment: in the same path with the file, the code is in the head section and it was working awhile ago it has just stopped working

Comment: code updated please review the second code